# xhtml label value unchangable

Tags: xhtml, label

i want to output some text in an label

```
<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" name="pizza1" value="Margherita">
```

is there a parameter that the text (value=Margherita) can't be changed, so the text is just displayed.

is input type= "text" the best way to output text? (later on the text is dynamic created)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i understood from you is that you need a tag that shows only text
if I was not wrong in understanding you
the answer is in your title
use label tag

```
<label id="pizza1">Margherita<label>
```

or you can just disable the textbox

```
<input type="text" size="20" maxlength="20" name="pizza1" value="Margherita" disabled="disabled">
```

I hope this what you want